# Lipschitz function and metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Suppose that $f:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$ is Lipschitz continuous and $x,y,z$ are elements of a metric space $(X,d)$. Fix $c,k>0$.

I'm reading a paper that says: if $z\in B(x,k)\cap B(y,k)$ and $d(x,y)\leq c$ with $B(x,k):=\{x'\in X:d(x',x)\leq k\}$, then
$\lvert f(d(x,z))-f(d(y,z))\rvert\leq Mc,$
for some $M>0$.

**Why?** Can you argue?

**My attempt**

Fristly, it seems that the fact that $z\in B(x,k)\cap B(y,k)$ is irrelevant.

Because $f$ is Lipschitzian, for some $M>0$, $$\lvert f(d(x,z))-f(d(y,z))\rvert\leq M \lvert d(x,z)-d(y,z)\rvert.$$

Also, it holds from the triangle inequality that

\begin{align}
d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)\\
d(y,z)\leq d(y,x)+d(x,z).
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
d(x,z)-d(y,z)\leq d(x,y)\\
-d(y,x)\leq d(x,z)-d(y,z).
\end{align}

This is equivalent to $\lvert d(x,z)-d(y,z)\rvert\leq d(x,y)$, and by hypothesis, $d(x,y)\leq c$.

Is this correct? Is there any other argument that is more efficient than this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your last inequality: $|d(x,z)-d(y,z)| \leqslant d(x,y)$, not $d(x,z)$. Everything else is OK and the proof is correct. I do not know a more efficient argument than that. (Also, the fact that $z  \in B(x,k)\cap B(y,k)$, or the value of $k$ do not affect anything. What is important is that $d(x,y) \leqslant c$).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, it was a typo!